# php password_verify() hash and pass won't match

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, truncate

I store my passwords in my database hashed with password_hash(), and I am trying to verify the passwords on login with password_verify(). For some reason password_verify() keeps returning false.

I read the documentation on this function and it said to make sure that the hash used in the function is between single quotes ' ' otherwise it will read the hash like it is three variables because of the $'s, so i tried writing $valid like this '$valid'. But that didn't work.

When I echo $valid the output is     $2y$10$zzZCN7UlukvY2skb3ELVp.4y3Oc7NJTEsFyqdstqYxT

When I echo $check the output is 123, which is the password used to create the account.

This is the part of my login.php, and this is where I feel the problem is.

```
$emailLogin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['emailLogin']);

$passLogin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['passLogin']);

$query = "SELECT `pass` FROM `user` WHERE `email`='$emailLogin'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$pass = $row['pass']; 

$key = VUP($passLogin, $pass);
```

This is part of my verify.php

```
function VUP($check, $valid){

if (password_verify($check, $valid)) {
$key = 1;

} else {
echo 'Invalid password.';
$key = 0;
die();
}
return $key;

}
```

Also part of verify.php

```
function SHP($password){

$hash = password_hash('$password', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

return $hash;

}
```

Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: May I suggest a full code change? You should put the query inside the function VUP, and you don't need to get the password from the database to check it, you can make mysql do the job.

Comment: You only need to use simple quotes if you use strings for testing. And `password_verify()` get a plain text password as the first parameter and a hashed one as the second one.

Comment: Ok I can move the query into VUP, but how do I verify without grabbing the pass from the database?

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code. Also make sure the column is long enough. MySQL will fail silently if it isn't.

Comment: `$2y$10$zzZCN7UlukvY2skb3ELVp.4y3Oc7NJTEsFyqdstqYxT` there you go, it's only 50 in length and is invalid/too short. It should be 60 (255 is suggested), so that wasn't stored correctly. You will need to increase your column's length, empty those rows and start over again. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php - *"Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice)."* - Want this as an answer? I think it should be.

Comment: Plus, you may also have a variable scope issue here.

Comment: I used error_reporting(-1);  and it did not report anything. Also it is connecting to the database and receiving the data without error.

Comment: Mike, check my answer and see if it works for you.

Comment: as I said in comments already, your code seems to check out, but MySQL will ***fail silently*** because of your **hash being too short.** Error reporting/checking will not help you in this case. Read my comment up there again.

Comment: @Fred -ii-  Thank you for catching that! I changed the column length and created a new user with new pass, the new has is now $2y$10$5M6nV2DUdWHQQFh.DAx03OMC9dZmiXcwVGZHrJruLz8P14EwiJHPW, which is long enough, but it is still not working

Comment: You're welcome and I already had my answer ready for this, which I've posted below. @MichaelSchroeder

Comment: @Phiter Fernandes I'm not sure how to make mysql  do the job without grabbing the data under pass

Comment: I have posted an answer ._.

Comment: @MichaelSchroeder Oh shoot, well see Phiter's answer then. Plus, you may also have a variable scope issue here also.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I'm looking into both possibilities and trying to find the problem.

Comment: @MichaelSchroeder pass your db connection to your functions, since as I said earlier, this could be a variable scope issue. You can also try using global inside them.

Comment: @MichaelSchroeder Your verify function needs to have a connection made to your database, that is what I feel is happening here (variable scope). So you'll need to either use `global $con;` or pass that connection to your function (which is better in most cases). I don't know if you're doing an "include" for the function, and if so, then that's what the other problem is.  I.e.: `function VUP($con, $check, $valid){` or `function VUP($check, $valid){ global $con` - Try both. Use `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));` instead of the one you have now.

Answer (score 5):

> *"When I echo $valid the output is $2y$10$zzZCN7UlukvY2skb3ELVp.4y3Oc7NJTEsFyqdstqYxT"*

`$2y$10$zzZCN7UlukvY2skb3ELVp.4y3Oc7NJTEsFyqdstqYxT` the hash is only 50 in length and is invalid/too short and as I said, MySQL will fail silently; error reporting/checking would not have helped here.

The password's column length should be 60 (255 is suggested), so it wasn't stored correctly originally.

You will need to clear your password column/or table, increase your column's length, and start over again.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> *"Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice)."*

---

You can also modify your query to read as:

```
$con = new mysqli("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $con->connect_errno . ') '
            . $con->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT `pass` FROM `user` WHERE `email`='$emailLogin'";
$result = $con->query($query);

// error checking on the query
if (!$result) {
    echo "<p>There was an error in query: $query</p>";
    echo $con->error;
}

$row_hash = $result->fetch_array();
if (password_verify($passLogin, $row_hash['pass'])) {
    echo "Success!";
}
```

---

Edit:

Adding from a comment I left to the OP:

Your verify function needs to have a connection made to your database, that is what I feel is happening here (variable scope). So you'll need to either use `global $con;` or pass the connection (variable) to your function (which is better in most cases).

I don't know if you're doing an "include" for the function, and if so, then that's what the other problem is.

I.e.: `function VUP($con, $check, $valid){` or `function VUP($check, $valid){ global $con;` - Try both. Use `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));` instead of the one you have now.